# How to search record between two date in gridview asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have data in sql table in which date col type is datetime(2019-04-30 15:01:14.000) ,now I want search record between two date in gridview.

I have tried code but it not working properly mean that if I want to search today record then in text boxes I will give today date and tomorrow date then today result will be display in gridview

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-5PJ76B9;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=SilverProduction;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");

            con.Open();

            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Searchbaledatewise");

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", DateTime.Parse(txtstart.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd ", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", DateTime.Parse(txtend.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                cmd.Connection = con;

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                da.Fill(dt);
                GVProducebale.DataSource = dt;
                GVProducebale.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
        }`
```

I want that if I give today date then today date data get represent in gridview.

Comment: Can you please clear the following doubt: In your textbook the user will give the to/from search date. You want to search the records between these dates (from the database) and show these records in the grid?

Comment: Also, do not use `AddWithValue`, its bad: http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: #peeyush singh, yes

Comment: DataTable dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => (x.Field<DateTime>("StartDate") <= DateTime.Now.Date) && (DateTime.Now.Date < x.Field<DateTime>("EndDate")).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: step 1 I would start with executing the stored procedure with the required dates and see if it is returning the proper results.

Comment: i have created Store procedure for searching

Comment: Could you please provide body of Searchbaledatewise ?

Comment: this code: con.Close(); should to be necessarily  executed

Comment: i have resolve this issue thanks Basil Kosovan